# How to handle batch file if need to kill the CMD's

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have to write a batch file which is suppose to kill all the currently running CMD processes, except one which is in Listening mode before regression runs. If there is any opened CMD in the same path as Regression, it ruines the regression. There would be probably 2 ways to achieve this:
1. Close all command prompts and start the listener (which can be done by calling a soft link).
2. Close all command prompts, except the one which would run the Regression.

I tried to kill the command prompts, however it ruined the regression as it killed the cmd which is expected to run the regression.

```
TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe /T
cd %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
"Regression Run.lnk"
```

If I go ahead with approach 1, tried to kill all cmd instances and then run the link, as soon as TASKKILL is called the cmd running itself is also killed. The other 2 lines were never ever called.

For the other approach, I am not able to get any method how to add any exception while calling TASKKILL.

If any one has better idea around it or suggest a better way to achieve it.

**Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using `TASKKILL /FI` to filter out the PID of the current cmd.exe shell you are running. I would like to know an easier way of getting the current cmd.exe PID.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\regtest.tmp"
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "processid=`'$pid`'").ParentProcessId" >"%TEMPFILE%"
SET /P "MYPID=" <"%TEMPFILE%"
ECHO MYPID is set to %MYPID%
IF EXIST "%TEMPFILE%" (DEL "%TEMPFILE%")

TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe"
TASKKILL /F /FI "PID ne %MYPID%" /IM cmd.exe
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my purpose partially (70%).
Appreciate your help.